# Pandas extends intervals in timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    product     timestamp               count
0   apple    2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00  1023
1   apple    2021-06-29 12:00:00-04:00  3790
2   apple    2021-06-29 13:00:00-04:00  128
3   apple    2021-06-29 14:00:00-04:00  0
4   apple    2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00  323
5   apple    2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00  4223
6   apple    2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00  1194
4   orange   2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00  23
5   orange   2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00  4289
```

As you can see for both the products (apple and orange) there is a count associated to an hour.
For the apple we have data in the time interval `2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00 - 2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00` while for the orange we have data in the time interval `2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00 - 2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00`.

I would like to extend the time interval so that for both product we have hourly data from the beginning to the end of the day, that is in the interval `2021-06-29 00:00:00-04:00 - 2021-06-29 23:00:00-04:00`.

The result would be the following:

```
    product     timestamp               count
0    apple    2021-06-29 00:00:00-04:00  0
1    apple    2021-06-29 01:00:00-04:00  0
2    apple    2021-06-29 02:00:00-04:00  0
3    apple    2021-06-29 03:00:00-04:00  0
4    apple    2021-06-29 04:00:00-04:00  0
5    apple    2021-06-29 05:00:00-04:00  0
6    apple    2021-06-29 06:00:00-04:00  0
7    apple    2021-06-29 07:00:00-04:00  0
8    apple    2021-06-29 08:00:00-04:00  0
9    apple    2021-06-29 09:00:00-04:00  0
10   apple    2021-06-29 10:00:00-04:00  0
11   apple    2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00  1023
12   apple    2021-06-29 12:00:00-04:00  3790
13   apple    2021-06-29 13:00:00-04:00  128
14   apple    2021-06-29 14:00:00-04:00  0
15   apple    2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00  323
16   apple    2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00  4223
17   apple    2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00  1194
18   apple    2021-06-29 18:00:00-04:00  0
19   apple    2021-06-29 19:00:00-04:00  0
20   apple    2021-06-29 20:00:00-04:00  0
21   apple    2021-06-29 21:00:00-04:00  0
22   apple    2021-06-29 22:00:00-04:00  0
23   apple    2021-06-29 23:00:00-04:00  0
24   orange    2021-06-29 00:00:00-04:00  0
25   orange    2021-06-29 01:00:00-04:00  0
26   orange    2021-06-29 02:00:00-04:00  0
27   orange    2021-06-29 03:00:00-04:00  0
28   orange    2021-06-29 04:00:00-04:00  0
29   orange    2021-06-29 05:00:00-04:00  0
30   orange    2021-06-29 06:00:00-04:00  0
31   orange    2021-06-29 07:00:00-04:00  0
32   orange    2021-06-29 08:00:00-04:00  0
33   orange    2021-06-29 09:00:00-04:00  0
34   orange    2021-06-29 10:00:00-04:00  0
35   orange    2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00  0
36   orange    2021-06-29 12:00:00-04:00  0
37   orange    2021-06-29 13:00:00-04:00  0
38   orange    2021-06-29 14:00:00-04:00  0
39   orange    2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00  23
40   orange    2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00  4289
41   orange    2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00  0
42   orange    2021-06-29 18:00:00-04:00  0
43   orange    2021-06-29 19:00:00-04:00  0
44   orange    2021-06-29 20:00:00-04:00  0
45   orange    2021-06-29 21:00:00-04:00  0
46   orange    2021-06-29 22:00:00-04:00  0
47   orange    2021-06-29 23:00:00-04:00  0
```

For far I tried to reindex the DataFrame but I am doing something wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you expect to handle the duplicate values?

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicate values in the data source: we can drop them. I just want to add a row for each one of hours that are not present in the original dataset and fill the count column with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

1. Convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) if not already:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

2. Find the start and end datetimes dynamically (this can be done statically as well) and create the range of hours:

   Dynamic:

   ```
   dates = df['timestamp'].dt.date
   date_range = pd.date_range(start=f'{dates.min()} 00:00:00-04:00',
                              end=f'{dates.max()} 23:00:00-04:00',
                              freq='H')
   ```

   Static:

   ```
   date_range = pd.date_range(start='2021-06-29 00:00:00-04:00',
                              end=f'2021-06-29 23:00:00-04:00',
                              freq='H')
   ```
3. Create a [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) based on the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) product values and the established `date_range`:

   ```
   midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
       [df['product'].unique(), date_range],
       names=['product', 'timestamp']
   )
   ```
4. [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to scale up the frame:

   ```
   df = (
       df.set_index(['product', 'timestamp'])
           .reindex(midx, fill_value=0)
           .reset_index()
   )
   ```

   `df`:

   ```
      product                 timestamp  count
   0    apple 2021-06-29 00:00:00-04:00      0
   1    apple 2021-06-29 01:00:00-04:00      0
   2    apple 2021-06-29 02:00:00-04:00      0
   3    apple 2021-06-29 03:00:00-04:00      0
   4    apple 2021-06-29 04:00:00-04:00      0
   5    apple 2021-06-29 05:00:00-04:00      0
   6    apple 2021-06-29 06:00:00-04:00      0
   7    apple 2021-06-29 07:00:00-04:00      0
   8    apple 2021-06-29 08:00:00-04:00      0
   9    apple 2021-06-29 09:00:00-04:00      0
   10   apple 2021-06-29 10:00:00-04:00      0
   11   apple 2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00   1023
   12   apple 2021-06-29 12:00:00-04:00   3790
   13   apple 2021-06-29 13:00:00-04:00    128
   14   apple 2021-06-29 14:00:00-04:00      0
   15   apple 2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00    323
   16   apple 2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00   4223
   17   apple 2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00   1194
   18   apple 2021-06-29 18:00:00-04:00      0
   19   apple 2021-06-29 19:00:00-04:00      0
   20   apple 2021-06-29 20:00:00-04:00      0
   21   apple 2021-06-29 21:00:00-04:00      0
   22   apple 2021-06-29 22:00:00-04:00      0
   23   apple 2021-06-29 23:00:00-04:00      0
   24  orange 2021-06-29 00:00:00-04:00      0
   25  orange 2021-06-29 01:00:00-04:00      0
   26  orange 2021-06-29 02:00:00-04:00      0
   27  orange 2021-06-29 03:00:00-04:00      0
   28  orange 2021-06-29 04:00:00-04:00      0
   29  orange 2021-06-29 05:00:00-04:00      0
   30  orange 2021-06-29 06:00:00-04:00      0
   31  orange 2021-06-29 07:00:00-04:00      0
   32  orange 2021-06-29 08:00:00-04:00      0
   33  orange 2021-06-29 09:00:00-04:00      0
   34  orange 2021-06-29 10:00:00-04:00      0
   35  orange 2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00      0
   36  orange 2021-06-29 12:00:00-04:00      0
   37  orange 2021-06-29 13:00:00-04:00      0
   38  orange 2021-06-29 14:00:00-04:00      0
   39  orange 2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00     23
   40  orange 2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00   4289
   41  orange 2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00      0
   42  orange 2021-06-29 18:00:00-04:00      0
   43  orange 2021-06-29 19:00:00-04:00      0
   44  orange 2021-06-29 20:00:00-04:00      0
   45  orange 2021-06-29 21:00:00-04:00      0
   46  orange 2021-06-29 22:00:00-04:00      0
   47  orange 2021-06-29 23:00:00-04:00      0
   ```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple',
                'orange', 'orange'],
    'timestamp': ['2021-06-29 11:00:00-04:00', '2021-06-29 12:00:00-04:00',
                  '2021-06-29 13:00:00-04:00', '2021-06-29 14:00:00-04:00',
                  '2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00', '2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00',
                  '2021-06-29 17:00:00-04:00', '2021-06-29 15:00:00-04:00',
                  '2021-06-29 16:00:00-04:00'],
    'count': [1023, 3790, 128, 0, 323, 4223, 1194, 23, 4289]
})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

dates = df['timestamp'].dt.date
date_range = pd.date_range(start=f'{dates.min()} 00:00:00-04:00',
                           end=f'{dates.max()} 23:00:00-04:00',
                           freq='H')
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df['product'].unique(), date_range],
    names=['product', 'timestamp']
)

df = (
    df.set_index(['product', 'timestamp'])
        .reindex(midx, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
)
```